# is there neural network architecture for unsupervised learning for topic modelling?

Tags: neural-networks, unsupervised-learning, topic-models

Let say i have a bunch of document and I want to analyse the topic of the corpus. The only way i know is to use unsupervised learning with gensim which use model like Latent Dirichlet allocation(LDA),Latent Semantic Indexing(LSi) or Hierarchical Dirichlet process(HDP). So i have a confusion

1. Is there any neural network architecture for topic analysis like this?
2. How to visualize result of LDA or LSI ? The only I know is use [pyLDAvis](https://pyldavis.readthedocs.io/), is there any alternative module for visualize?

Thanks